# Safari - Adding content in iframe with javascript CSS issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, safari

I'm adding some HTML in an iframe:

```
<div class="parentClass">
   <div class="classChild1">block 1 content</div>
   <div class="classChild2">block 2 content</div>
<div>
```

My `classChild1` has no CSS rules defined (but it should) and it refuses to be triggered in JavaScript. 
I tried to:

```
console.log(myIframeContent.find('.classChild1'));
// Output 0
```

When I directly change the element from the DOM and add some class, I get my css back and everything works fine. But since I can't find it from JavaScript I can't manipulate this block.

Everything is working fine for the `classChild2` even the css which is defined is the same .css and I got no problem in Chrome/IE/Firefox.

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the whole code to see how you are adding what and where. Also it would be interesting from where the javascript you show is actually called.